# Selecting items from multiple user types with UNION JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have an issue here . i have 3 tables namely `tbl_ads, tbl_ps, tbl_dealer`

```
tbl_ads ( ad_id, ad_type, poster_id,  cat,  title, description, images ... , ad_status )

tbl_ps ( ps_id, name , address, city, state )

tbl_dealer ( id, name , address, city, state, pack, bussname )
```

now i want to search the ads based on `title`, `description` in `tbl_ads` but i want to search the ads based on the `city` and `state` which are in different tables depending on the tbl_ads

basically here, i want to get ads where if `ad_type = 'ps'` then get from `tbl_ps` and `if ad_type = 'dealer'` then get from tbl_dealer .. the relationship between the table `ad` and `ps` is **`tbl_ps.ps_id = poster_id`** and the **relationship** between the table `ad` and `dealer` is **`tbl_dealer.id = poster_id`**

The issue is i want to search ads based on the ad `title`, ad `description`, `city` and `state` and get a combined result of tbl_ads records only which may be ps or dealers

the city and state resides both on ps and dealer tables

i have tried all the multiple join, union and all the thing that i got from this stack overflow . i am not getting actually what i want and its really going into hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some thing like this maybe.

```
SELECT ad_id,ad_type,poster_id,cat,title,description,images,ad_status,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.name, dealer.name) as name,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.address, dealer.address) as address,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.city, dealer.city) as city,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.state, dealer.state) as state,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', NULL, dealer.pack) as pack,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', NULL, dealer.bussname) as bussname
FROM tbl_ads ads
LEFT JOIN tbl_ps ps ON (ps.ps_id = ads.poster_id)
LEFT JOIN tbl_dealer dealer ON (dealer.id = ads.poster_id)
```

then so search you can use something like this

```
SELECT ad_id,ad_type,poster_id,cat,title,description,images,ad_status,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.name, dealer.name) as _name,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.address, dealer.address) as _address,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.city, dealer.city) as _city,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', ps.state, dealer.state) as _state,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', NULL, dealer.pack) as _pack,
       IF (ad_type = 'ps', NULL, dealer.bussname) as _bussname
FROM tbl_ads ads
LEFT JOIN tbl_ps ps ON (ps.ps_id = ads.poster_id)
LEFT JOIN tbl_dealer dealer ON (dealer.id = ads.poster_id)
WHERE title LIKE '%tit%'
   OR description LIKE '%crip%'
HAVING _city LIKE '%Yorba%'
    OR _state LIKE '%Cali%'
```

check this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f685/1/0)

This is a very basic search, searching can get intense like the order of matching title over matching description and things like how many matching terms in title for example.

Comment: thanks i got it ... with the some modifications do u want the solution that i was expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `CASE` statement is best in this situation.

**[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d500e/1/0)**

### SQL

```
SELECT ad_id, ad_type, title, description,
  case ad_type
    when 'ps'
      then (select city from tbl_ps where ps_id=poster_id)
    when 'dealer'
      then (select city from tbl_dealer where id=poster_id)
  end as CITY,
  case ad_type
    when 'ps'
      then (select state from tbl_ps where ps_id=poster_id)
    when 'dealer'
      then (select state from tbl_dealer where id=poster_id)
  end as STATE
from tbl_ads
```

Comment: nice one it helped in some way

Answer (score 0):

If you have post data then you can try this:

**EDIT:**
Table struuctre should be:

```
tbl_ads ( ad_id, ad_type, poster_id,  cat,  title, description, images ... , ad_status )

tbl_ps (id, name , address, city, state )

tbl_dealer ( id, name , address, city, state, pack, bussname )
```

Just rename `ps_id` to `id` and then :

```
    $strTable = isset($_REQUEST['ads_type']) && $_REQUEST['ads_type']=="ps"  ? "tbl_ps" : "tbl_dealer";

     $sql = "SELECT * from  tbl_ads as t1 INNER JOIN ".$strTable." as t2 on t1.poster_id =  t2.id  ";
//execute your query
```

OLD:

First you need to check your ads type like this :

```
If (isset($_REQUEST['ads_type'])){

$bolIsheader = $_REQUEST['ads_type'] == "ps" ? false : true;
if($bolIsheader)
$strSql = "
SELECT * from  tbl_ads as t1 INNER JOIN  
tbl_dealer as t2 on t1.poster_id= t2.id  ";
else
$strSql = "
SELECT * from  tbl_ads as t1 INNER JOIN  tbl_ps as t2 on t1.poster_id =  t2.ps_id ";
//next execute your query
}
```